# Call a custom controller action method from a 'link_to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, hyperlink

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to state an action method in a my controller file so that in my view files I can use something like the following:

```
link_to("Delete", posts_path(@post.id), :method => :delete)
```

That is, to have a link so that I can "directly" call and run an action method in my controller.

In the above code, for example, it is possible to call the `destroy` method adding `:method => :delete`.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Views are called by controllers, not the other way around. Doing what you intend breaks the MVC-ness of your application and creates a dependency on the controller within the view. You might be able to accomplish this with some fancy routes, but I don't know what that would look like off the top of my head.

Comment: The question makes zero sense to me. What is being described is exactly mvc. Please elaborate.

Comment: This is perfectly MVC. Why is it not MVC and what would be the MVC way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.It works in my case.

```
 <%= link_to(t(:delete), :action => 'destroy', :method => :delete, :id => @post.id ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would stick by the advisement of your comments, but the syntax would be:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => @post.id} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `posts_path` to `post_path` :

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

or, even better,

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Also, to link to another action, add a route for it,
e.g. `resources :posts, :member => [:mycustomaction]` and in your view `<%= link_to("foobar", mycustomaction_post_path(post) %>`

Comment: Sorry for my earlier wrong answer... Rails3 properly handles link_to making a POST here when you're using restful routes and rails.js. There may still be some benefit to using `button_to` for compatibility